# TFS 2015 VSS Query Result Button

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-2015

I'm trying create TFS 2015 on-prem VSS Extension. I want add button to query result button panel. 
I read msdn, get example from GITHub () and try add extension to my TFS.

In this example many of buttons adding to several places (Work Item button panel, Context Menu etc), but button to query result dosen't work.

MSDN (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/targets/overview#work) says, that target for query result button panel is ms.vss-work-web.work-item-query-results-toolbar-menu. So that vss-extension.json

```
{
        "id": "showProperties_24",
        "type": "ms.vss-web.action",
        "description": "Shows the target properties for work item query results toolbar menu.",
        "targets": [
            "ms.vss-work-web.work-item-query-results-toolbar-menu"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "text": "Custom query results toolbar menu",
            "title": "ms.vss-work-web.work-item-query-results-toolbar-menu (Custom query results toolbar action)",
            "icon": "images/show-properties.png",
            "group": "actions",
            "uri": "main.html",
            "registeredObjectId": "showProperties"
        }
    },
```

But it dosen't work

[image: Screenshot]

Can someone explain what is wrong

Comment: Here link to GitHUb example https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/tree/master/contributions-guide

Comment: Based on my test with VSTS and TFS 2015 update 3, the custom query result tool bar button doesn't show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new extension for query result toolbar menu with Visual Studio Team Services and TFS 2015 update 3 (refer to the source code of that sample: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/tree/master/contributions-guide). It works fine for Visual Studio Team Services.

[image]

It doesn’t work fine for TFS 2015 update 3, you can check these screenshot, for worked extension, it would load the extension, but for query result toolbar menu extension, it wouldn’t load the extension. Also, the article you provided is applied for Visual Studio Team Services, so, to conclude, it isn’t applied for TFS 2015 now. You could check it with next update for TFS on-permission.

[image]

[image]